# qml file not work in qrc?

Tags: qt, qml

platform: win8, qt5.0

```
this->engine = new QQmlEngine;
this->component = new QQmlComponent(this->engine, ":/Foodie.qml");
this->mainWindow = new QQuickWindow;


while(this->component->isReady()) {
    this->mainItem = qobject_cast<QQuickItem*>(component->create());
    this->mainItem->setParentItem(this->mainWindow->contentItem());
    break;
}



<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>Foodie.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
see this passage..  component would not load auto.
```

> https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-12916